# converting html to image not working

Tags: php, html, image, php-gd

I use this script to make html code into image using php-gd library:

```
<?php
    //put your html code here 
    $html_code = ' 
    <html> 
        <body> 
            Image Out Put sadadasdasdasdasdasd
        </body> 
    </html>
    '; 

    $img = imagecreate("300", "600"); 
    imagecolorallocate($img,0,0,0); 
    $c2 = imagecolorallocate($img,70,70,70); 
    imageline($img,0,0,300,600,$c2); 
    imageline($img,300,0,0,600,$c2); 

    $white = imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 255, 255); 
    imagettftext($img, 9, 0, 1, 1, $white, "arial.ttf", $html_code); 

    header('Content-type: image/jpeg'); 
    imagejpeg($img); 

?>
```

site url:

http://almogas.com/temp/phpimage.php?id=3

I get lot of unknown characters. How can I fix this behavior?

///////////////////////////////////////////////

**edit**

now its working after delete the spaces

but there is way to add background  image?
thank you

Comment: What do you mean with _unknown char_? How do you expect this to work?

Comment: The `Content-Type` header is not sent properly. The Document has the Content-Type `text/html`.

Comment: OP is trying to create an image so that is not the correct `Content-Type` @Le_Morri

Comment: Thats what I am saying. his given code is right. But the server is not doing it.

Comment: @putvande this works. have you checked the output?

Comment: Do you have the file 'arial.ttf' in the same folder as your PHP script?

Comment: I downloaded the link provided removed 1 space and 2 carriage returns and saved back. you can see the image. black background with white text and a diagonal cross across the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have unwanted chars before `<?`. remove all blank lines and spaces before `<?` your image is otherwise correct.

`<?` must be the first character first line in your script. you can avoid `?>` if you use it it must be the last line last chars.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that your file start without spaces or extra chars.
It is important that it starts with

```
<?
```

You can avoid the closing

```
?>
```

So that you're sure to not send any other unwanted output to the client.

Comment: thank you all. now there is way to add bg image? thank you

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure you have the GD library enabled on your server.
- You should use png instead of jpg as png produces better text quality
- You should use imagedestroy after imagejpeg or imagepng to clean up memory